# How do i get to study the impact of body bias on NMOS threshold voltage using LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, nmos

I am new to LTSpice.
I have tried a design in LTSpice for the above requirement. But I dont get the plot for different values of body bias Vsb.

Answer (score 1):

> plot for different values

You can use the .step command to perform a up to 3 variables monte carlo simulation

https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-the-step-command-to-perform-repeated-analysis.html#

If you search around some guys posted also some clever tricks to overcome the 3 parameter limit to some extend

Answer (score 0):

You need a have a good spice model for nmos.  Place a variable voltage between source and body and sweep the voltage and plot the results. Also you can follow @schnedan solution for Monte Carlo simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Got it working now.

Modelled three circuits for different values of VBS and performed DC sweep on Vgs to observe the variation.
If the requirement is for a single plot showing the cases for each value of Vbs, then it could be specified as variable {Vbs} for the DC voltage source added to represent Vbs and then ".step parameter  Vbs [initial val] [final] [step]" in LTSpice.